# How can I change the color of the editor group header when tabs are hidden in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, tabs

I'm currently using `Gruvbox Dark Hard` theme but whenever I disable tabs, the background color of it looks very off. How can I make it so it has the same color as when Tabs are enabled (but not focused!)?

[image: Color that is off]
^ Color that is off

[image: Color that I want when tabs are enabled but not focused.]
^Color that I want (of tabs that are NOT focused).

I tried already setting up:

```json
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#0000FF",
    "editorGroupHeader.tabsBorder": "#0F6C8C",
    "editorGroupHeader.border": "#FF5010",
  }
}
```

But these all seem to work only if you have tabs enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the colour customization setting you're looking for is `editorGroupHeader.noTabsBackground`.

Its description:

> Background color of the editor group title header when tabs are disabled (`"workbench.editor.showTabs": false`). Editor groups are the containers of editors.